# When is it theoretically possible to fit PCB circuit on x Layers (emphasis: x =1)

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, math, theory, pcb-layers

When is it **theoretically** possible to fit a given circuit on a certain number of layers?
  (Presumably PCB layers.)

What is/are the name of the mathematics/algorithms that might determine this, or what are some implementations that will determine this for you?

I know this may not be the most immediately practical question, but this pertains to when it *can* be done.

Comment: If you allow traces under jumpers, there's probably no topology that couldn't be done on a one-layer board. Of course there's technologies (like fine-pitch BGA or microstrip geometry) that require multiple layers.

Comment: For the purposes of this question sir, let's assume the topology of current flow must be wholly 2D - unless you have something highly generalized.  **Extreme** example: you can describe a 4D board with 3D layers, rather than 3D board with 2D layers?

Comment: I have a feeling the proof for such a thing would have a lot of similarities to the [Four color theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_color_theorem) which was a tough one to prove.

Comment: @user1833028 - How theoretical is the question? Please explain the question in a bit more detail. Are PCB design rules (i.e. minimum track width and space) also constraints? Is the current carrying capacity, and so minimum track width  also a constraint? Is voltage between tracks (e.g. jumping between tracks) a constraint? Are specific component sizes  constraints, or can components take any available size, or are sizes excluded as constraints? Are all electrical properties of the circuit constraints (e.g. EMI emission, ground loops, capacitance, heat dissipation, ...)?

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a mathematical question.

I would think that if the circuit is represented by a [planar graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph) it would be possible to use a single layer board to implement it. See [this](https://www.era.lib.ed.ac.uk/handle/1842/6660) reference, for example.

Comment: Do you think it would be more appropriate to rehash this, and put on math stack exchange with a linkback?

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for a mathematics answer, so sure.

Comment: Components give you free bridges, so the purely mathematic answer is going to be pessimistic.

Comment: I don't think the answer is exclusively mathematical. Many designs require specific conditions in the circuit (EMI, RF, decoupling, etc.) that might be impossible to achieve with only a topological solution. Also, any number of layers can use jumpers, and any except one can use vias, uvias, buried vias, etc, that would deeply affect the outcome. Making a PCB is NOT just making the connections, except for the simplest of the circuits.

Comment: @GuillermoPrandi No kidding. *Especially* single-sided boards. Placement is really where the smarts are, the actual routing usually goes pretty simply when the placement is done right unless the density is way too high.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this problem has a simple to define mathematical solution.  To see if a given circuit can be routed or not, one typically uses an auto-routing program, which can try hundreds of solutions before either giving up or declaring that a routing exists.  But then you could rearrange the components on the board, and go through this again.  In any case, after going through the routing process, you have to do a DRC (Design Rule Check) to see if there are any problems with traces too close to other traces or pins, etc., which may affect your layout again.

So if there is a mathematical description of an auto-router available, that would most likely be a candidate for the algorithm you are looking for.

If you start with multiple layers, say 4, 6 or 8 depending one the complexity of the circuit, and it routes pretty quickly, then you can reduce the number of layers and try it again until it has difficulty routing.  Then stop.

If you want to have a one-layer board, then you will almost certainly need jumpers, since there will inevitably be some areas in the layout where traces need to cross.  Although some layout programs handle jumpers in a situation like this automatically, ones like Eagle do not.  There the simplest solution is to pretend the PCB is a two-layer board, and give the top layer (the one with components) a high "cost" so it won't try to put traces there unless absolutely necessary.  The traces on the top will never actually exist (since you won't be etching that side), but instead these traces will represent the jumpers.

When the board is routed, you will want to make sure the traces representing the jumpers don't go under any components (if they were real traces, they could, so the router likely will try to to put some there).  If there ae, manually move them.  When the board is stuffed, just put wires between the vias representing the ends of the traces.